# Javascript appendChild not working for li element

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code works up to the last `append`. This I checked with alert messages. All the alerts except for the last one get displayed. So I assume the problem is with the last `append`. Can someone please help?

```js
var node = document.createElement("li");
var d0 = document.createElement("div");

var d1 = document.createElement("div");
var L1 = document.createElement("label");

d1.append(L1);

L1.innerHTML = "datah[key]";


var d2 = document.createElement("div");
var L2 = document.createElement("label");
d2.append(L2);

L2.innerHTML = "datah1[key]";

console.log("test1");
d0.append(d1);
d0.append(d2);

node.append(d0);
console.log("test2");

document.getElementById("speclist").appendChild(node);
// The following alert doesn't get printed
console.log("test3");
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="speclist">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "All the alerts except for the last one get displayed" — The last one is displayed when I run that code.

Comment: Look at the Console in your browser's developer tools. Read the error messages.

Comment: 10 to 1 says [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: All alerts displayed when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with last append problem is that you are not wrapping "test3" in any html.you want to show test3 then you have to wrap it with node(li).

```js
var node = document.createElement("li");
var d0 = document.createElement("div");

var d1 = document.createElement("div");
var L1 = document.createElement("label");

d1.append(L1);

L1.innerHTML = "datah[key]";


var d2 = document.createElement("div");
var L2 = document.createElement("label");
d2.append(L2);

L2.innerHTML = "datah1[key]";

alert("test1");
d0.append(d1);
d0.append(d2);

node.append(d0);
alert("test2");

//document.getElementById("speclist").appendChild(node);
// The following alert doesn't get printed
alert("test3");

  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test3"));
  document.getElementById("speclist").appendChild(node);
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="speclist">

  </ul>
</div>
```

and one more thing when i am running your code it is showing me 3 alerts test1,test2 and test3.